# Javascript Sys.Application.add_init

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I am seeing a weird error from javascript while initializing a control after the page is loaded.. the code is already deployed, it could be buggy but would like to know the reason for the error. Please note that it works for everyone (there are 100s of users) except for a couple of users with IE 8 on Windows 7 (works for others with the same environment).

It goes like this:

I have a user control with a button. null reference error is thrown when the user clicks on a button and the method that handles the click event is trying to access a control which is initialized in a handler added to `Sys.Application.add_init`.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var LoadingLabel;
Sys.Application.add_init(PageControlInitHandler);
function PageControlInitHandler() {
    LoadingLabel = $get('<%= lblLoading.ClientID %>');
}
function ButtonIsClicked() {
    LoadingLabel.innerText = "Some text";
    : // some code here
    return false;
}
</script>

<asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/SomeImage.gif" ID="SomeButton" runat="server"
        OnClientClick="return ButtonIsClicked()" />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLoading" Text="Loading.." />
```

The code can be improved but I was wondering why it breaks only on certain machines and if so would like to find out some specific IE setting might have an influence.

Thanks a lot in advance!!
Sajid

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, seems like the user is clicking the button before the full initialization happens.  So I would guess what's happening is that either they are really moving through the application fast, or their computers could be slower (meaning slower rendering time) and they may have a slower internet connection, thus causing the page to run slower and these weird errors happen to occur.  I've experienced this one (both computer slowness and network slowness) as being the cause of these kinds of issues.

Or there was some random error in the framework that caused the page to break, and the user didn't notice it.

Comment: Thanks Brian. The problem seems like something very specific to this machine. We were able to reproduce almost the similar behavior in our testing environment by throttling the internet speed to very slow connection.

Comment: Thanks Brian. The problem seems like something very specific to this machine. And when we investigated live in the client's pc (Win 7 + IE8) with IE Developer tools we saw there are many "object expected" and "Invalid character" errors when downloading ajax script with the url "ScriptResource.axd?d=LOnh..." and we have tried this url directly and the result is weird. there are 3 downloads, one of them is okay but 2 others are full of junk characters, looks like binary/encrypted. we disabled all the IE add-ins/anti-virus and tried but still the same.

Comment: OK, very slow connections can be problematic like this, especially since scripts can time out and such... you can also try to use FireFox + FireBug to see if that gives you any additional clues.  FireBug is pretty handy and the console/script debugger/net panel can point out additional problems.